# how can I solve this problem ModuleNotFoundError in the prettytable package

Tags: python

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable()
print(table)
```

When I ran it I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\PROJECTS\newwww.py", line 1, in <module>
    from prettytable import PrettyTable
  File "E:\PROJECTS\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\prettytable\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import importlib.metadata
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _adapters, _meta
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\metadata\_adapters.py", line 3, in <module>
    import email.message
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.message'; 'email' is not a package
```

Can anyone help, I reinstalled it multiple times.

Comment: try: `from email.message import EmailMessage`

Comment: Do you have a file called `email.py` lying around somewhere?